# Get the lowest date out of a set based on priority ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, min

I have got the following priority list table where Source4 takes priority over 3, 3 over 2, 2 over 1, and so on.

| SourceID | SourceDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Source1 |
| 2 | Source2 |
| 3 | Source3 |
| 4 | Source4 |

I also have the following table with data (however the table will contain multiple disitinct EventIDs)

| EventID | CommencingTime | SourceID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-10-24 11:27:34 | 1 |
| 12346 | 2021-10-24 11:27:34 | 1 |
| 12347 | 2021-10-24 11:27:34 | 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |
| 12346 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |
| 12347 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |
| 12345 | 2021-10-24 10:58:00 | 2 |
| 12346 | 2021-10-24 10:58:00 | 2 |
| 12347 | 2021-10-24 10:58:00 | 2 |

How can I get the lowest date from the above based on the priority list.

In this case the correct result set would be:

| EventID | CommencingTime | SourceID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |
| 12346 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |
| 12347 | 2021-10-24 12:58:55 | 3 |

I have tried doing a `MIN OVER PARTITION BY ORDER BY SourceID DESC`, but that just keeps returning 2021-10-24 10:58:00 and ignores the priority SourceID

Comment: I have tried doing a MIN OVER PARTITION BY ORDER BY SourceID DESC, but that just keeps returning 2021-10-24 10:58:00 and ignores the priority SourceID

Comment: Is there a reason why EventID `12345` is the only row that is returned when `12346` and `12347` also have the same date and priority source id?

Comment: @ggordon, sorry mistake. corrected now. It can actually return all events as long as it respects the priority list order. so in this case it would return 12345, 12346, 12347 but all with 2021-10-24 12:58:55

Comment: @thatsweetguy Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `rank` to achieve this based on your sample shared

```sql
select 
    EventID,CommencingTime,SourceID
from (
    select
        *,
        rank() over (order by SourceID DESC,CommencingTime) as rn
    from
       mytable
) t
where rn=1
```

[View working demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e8e5fffbe52a57543410315851486b4a)